# What's the different between Auto-generated and specific return type of stored procedure in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have a stored procedure `Get_All_Customers`, it selects 4 columns from the `Customers` table. The result is displayed in a `DataGridView`.

There are 2 cases when calling the stored procedure:

- When the return type be auto-generated:

  - the `DataGridView` will contain the 4 columns that the stored procedure selects
- When the return type be specific (`Customer`):

  - The `DataGridView` will contain 5 columns (not 4 that the stored procedure selects)

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. In addition, describe what you already tried.

Comment: This is the key: the SP doesn't *know* it returns Customer data, it only knows it returns rows having 4 fields. So an auto-generated type is not aware of a fifth field in the original table.

Comment: wha's a bout Customer return , why it return 5 fields ???

Comment: It doesn't. Customer happens to have 5 properties, only 4 are filled by the SP. The fifth may show its default value.